# Android splash screen ImageView not loading

Tags: android, imageview, splash-screen

My Android application is supposed to show a splash screen consisting solely of an ImageView while it is still loading. The ImageView should just display a local resource. Here is my code:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ImageView splash = new ImageView(this);
        splash.setImageResource(R.drawable.splashImage);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setId(R.id.gameView);
        uilayout addView(splash, someLayoutParams);
        setContentView(layout, someOtherLayoutParams);
        // with a return-statement, the image would be displayed now

        final GameActivity activity = this;
        this.findViewById(R.id.gameView).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // this is supposed to wait until the image has been fully loaded
                activity.init(this);
            }
        });
    }

    public void init(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener) {
        try {
            findViewById(R.id.gameView).getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError x) {
            findViewById(R.id.gameView).getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
        } finally {
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            // lots of stuff
            setContentView(layout);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that as soon as I execute code after the first call for setContentView(), my **splash screen image is not displayed** and the new layout immediately shows up.
I would appreciate any help on how to solve this problem.

**EDIT:**
It was my fault to assume that my code was the ideal solution for a splash screen. [This](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) tutorial really helped me out. My solution based on this tutorial:

*@drawable/layer-list_splash*:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/color_background"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/sprite_splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and my *styles.xml*:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/layers_splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: try to make the view in a XML file

Comment: @Fakher the use of a XML file didn't solve the problem for me

Comment: @Fakher My xml code solely contained an ImageView in a RelativeLayout exactly how it would have been created programmatically in the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about running the activity.init() after 2 secs to show the splash screen?

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.init();
        }
    }, 2000)
```

Comment: This seems to be the best workaround for me right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can Do Something Like This

1. By Making This Following Activity
   (SplashScreen.java) as Your Launcher Activity(Main Entry point for your app).
2. Create A Separate Layout for splash image.

**splash.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TheSplashLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/SplashImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/your_splash_image"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**SplashScreen.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.example.harsh.gmfbp.R;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    /**
     * The thread to process splash screen events
     */
    private Thread mSplashThread;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Splash screen view
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this;

        // The thread to wait for splash screen events
        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        wait(5000);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){
                }

                finish();

                // Run next activity which is your GameActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class); //Here You Can Replace MainActivity.class with your GameActivity

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };

        mSplashThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Processes splash screen touch events
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            synchronized(mSplashThread){
                mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion, but I would prefer an implementation that doesn't add any delay to the loading time caused by the init()-method